# How can we modify the training dataset to achieve better accuracy on the minority class for any classification algorithm?

Tags: machine-learning, classification

In many training datasets, the class distribution is skewed, I.e. one class is very frequent (e.g. 95%), while another is rare (e.g. 5%). In such applications, the Naive classifier that assigns all test cases to the majority class achieves very high accuracy. However, the Naive classifier does not predict any cases of the minority class, although it is often more important than the majority class.

So are there any ways to improve the accuracy on the minority class just by modifying the training dataset? or Do we have to modify the classification algorithm as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the issue of the Imbalanced classification. Below are the methods used to treat the Imbalanced Datasets.

1.Undersampling
2.Oversampling
3.Synthetic Data Generation
4.Cost-Sensitive Learning

1.Undersampling

This method works with the majority class. It reduces the number of observations from the majority class to make the data set balanced. This method is best to use when the data set is huge and reducing the number of training samples helps to improve run time and storage troubles.
Undersampling methods are of 2 types: Random and Informative.

2. Oversampling

This method works with minority class. It replicates the observations from minority class to balance the data. It is also known as upsampling. Similar to undersampling, this method also can be divided into two types: Random Oversampling and Informative Oversampling.

3. Synthetic Data Generation

In simple words, instead of replicating and adding observations from the minority class, it overcomes imbalances by generates artificial data. It is also a type of oversampling technique.

In regards to synthetic data generation, synthetic minority oversampling technique (SMOTE) is a powerful and widely used method. SMOTE algorithm creates artificial data based on feature space (rather than data space) similarities from minority samples. We can also say, it generates a random set of minority class observations to shift the classifier learning bias towards minority class.

4. Cost-Sensitive Learning (CSL)
   It is another commonly used method to handle classification problems with imbalanced data. It’s an interesting method. In simple words, this method evaluates the cost associated with misclassifying observations.

It does not create a balanced data distribution. Instead, it highlights the imbalanced learning problem by using cost matrices which describe the cost for misclassification in a particular scenario. Recent researches have shown that cost-sensitive learning has many times outperformed sampling methods. Therefore, this method provides a likely alternative to sampling methods.

To build these in R refer the link https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2016/03/practical-guide-deal-imbalanced-classification-problems/

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways. You can upsample miority class, downsample majority, do some weighting based on loss, or some other measures. As you've tagged your post to be related to TF I suggest you look at Importance Sampling for Keras, http://idiap.ch/~katharas/importance-sampling/ it has some ready to use wrappers that you put around your model.